# Microsoft.Update.Session does not show recent updates

Tags: powershell, windows-update

We use WSUS for Windows Updates and now and then I would like to check if updates were installed when I intended them to do so. I combined some ideas from others and ended up with this PowerShell script:

```
Param(
        [Parameter(Position =1, Mandatory = $true)]$ComputerName,
        $NumberOfUpdates = 20,
        [switch]$all
       )

foreach($computer in $ComputerName){

    $Session = [Activator]::CreateInstance([type]::GetTypeFromProgID("Microsoft.Update.Session",$computer))
    $Searcher = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher()
    if($all)
    {
        $HistoryCount = $Searcher.GetTotalHistoryCount()
        $updates = $Searcher.QueryHistory(1,$HistoryCount)
    }
    Else { $updates = $Searcher.QueryHistory(1,$NumberOfUpdates) }

    $computer
    $updates | Select Date, Title | Format-Table
}
```

It does its job, **except** that it does not show recently installed updates.

I was monitoring the status of an update yesterday.

- The update was installed 21:08
- The server rebooted 21:10

At first, my script did not show any changes on the remote computer so I started a timer running the script every 10 minutes and logging the output before I went to bed.

This morning I discovered that 02:17, more than 5 hours later, the update now showed in the output from `Microsoft.Update.Session`